# Simple C programming code containing nodes runs but creates an error on codeblock

Tags: c, nodes, codeblocks

//this program creates a struct node with 2 pointer variables, an airport and a link to another node. It simply links toronto, miami and boston airport and prints it out through a while loop. The code works but i get point.exe stopped working. I took a picture.https://gyazo.com/e58ba30ea0da3e8039ad445fb3128d21

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node{
    char * AIRPORT[4];
    struct node * LINK;

} nodez;

int main (){
    nodez *J,*K;
    J = malloc(sizeof(nodez));
    if (J == NULL){
        return 1;

    }
    strcpy(J->AIRPORT, "TOR");
    J->LINK = malloc(sizeof(nodez));
    if (J -> LINK == NULL){
        return 1;

    }
    strcpy(J->LINK->AIRPORT, "MIA");
    J->LINK->LINK = malloc(sizeof(nodez));
    if (J -> LINK -> LINK == NULL){
        return 1;

    }
    strcpy(J->LINK-> LINK -> AIRPORT, "BOS");

    nodez *current = J;
    while (current){
        printf("%s\n", current -> AIRPORT);
        current = current -> LINK;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a picture of what i get

Comment: `strcpy(J->AIRPORT, "TOR")` - `J->AIRPORT` is not a `char` array.

Comment: That would need `char * AIRPORT[4];` --> `char AIRPORT[4];` but also be very careful when chasing links. In a linked list, you should check every link pointer before running ahead. And the badly formatted code is difficult to read.

Comment: please tell me the formatting is due to having trouble with the interface here, and is not really how you format your `if` statements.

Comment: Also, you should set the node after `BOS` to `null` or `0`

Comment: 1) Format this mess properly. 2) Text has to be **in the question itself**, no images, no links! 3) See [ask]

Comment: @Riley: What is `null`? That is not part of the C standard.

Comment: @Olaf The standard consistently uses `null` to reference things with the value `0`. "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant" or "A byte with all bits zero shall be interpreted as a null character".

Comment: @Olaf I'm assuming you are trying talk about the macro `NULL`

Comment: @Riley whatever the standard might say, there is less confusion if you use the term `nul` to indicate the character `'\0'` as shown in the ASCII charts. You said ""A byte with all bits zero shall be interpreted as a null character". That is unrelated to pointer values.

Comment: @Riley: As you write it in code-tags, you mean an identifer. While there is the macro `NULL`, which evaluates to a _null pointer constants_, there is no standard name `null`. Nor does the standard write about _null_ as itself, but a _**null pointer constant**_ and (elsewhere) about _null pointers_, but never _null_ by itself. Similar for the (unrelated) _null **character**_. Also a _null pointer_ is not the same as the _integer value_ `0`. The _null pointer_ need not have an all-bits-zero representation.

Comment: @Olaf That's even less clear. `struct node*` is not a character.

Comment: @Riley: It was not me starting with _null characters_! And I clearly wrote it is unrelated.

Comment: ty for the help guys, i'm really new to programming in general so i do not understand what you mean by char * AIRPORT[4] not being an array but it works nonetheless and the error i found was that i did not set the last link to NULL, thereby the whileloop iterates one more printloop then nessesary. Adding this line worked:
J->LINK-> LINK -> LINK = 'NULL';

Comment: Did that cure the compiler warnings, which you should have enabled? Your array of pointers has enough *space* but is of the wrong type.

Comment: @bossrevs: Of course `AIRPORT` is an array!

Comment: @Weather Vane my code has tons of warnings but as i said, i'm retarded when it comes to coding and I see the diagnoses but do not know what they even mean. I'm using learn-c.org to learn this and this is my best attempt so far. 
I tried changing it to char AIRPORT[4] and the code just fails to work.
i need that astrisk thingy to make this code work. give me a year and i'll be at a level where you and i can talk without me being confused as hell

Comment: You should definitely look into how to use a debugger to investigate what's going on.

Comment: " The code works but i get point.exe stopped working. "  - so, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `AIRPORT` member of the `nodez` structure should be defined as `char AIRPORT[4];`, as currently defined it is an array of 4 pointer to `char`. The compiler produces warnings that should not be ignored.

Furthermore, you construct a list of linked nodes but forget to set the `LINK` of the last node to `NULL`. `malloc()` returns uninitialized memory, the `LINK` member probably contains an invalid address, invoking undefined behavior when you iterate through the list.

Fix it by setting `J->LINK->LINK->LINK = NULL;` after the last `strcpy()`.